# How to replace default argument in __init__ method in a unittest

Tags: python

I have a class under test that exposes an argument in `__init__` just for testing.  It looks like this

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self, start_time=None):
    if start_time is None:
      start_time = time.time()
```

In my test, I want to pass in start_time using a fake time, so I get a time in `setUp()` first and then pass it to every test method.

```
class MyclassTest(TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.fake_start_time = time.time()

  def test_one(self):
    x = MyClass(start_time=self.fake_start_time)
    ...

  def test_two(self):
    x = MyClass(start_time=self.fake_start_time)
    ...
```

All this works, but I'm wondering if there's a way for me to avoid having to write `start_time=self.fake_start_time` in every single test.  Can I somehow replace the `__init__` method's default argument in `setUp()`?

I figured out an ugly way to do it, but was wondering if there's a more standard approach, possibly based on `mock.patch`?

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of the class in `setUp`:

```
def setUp(self)
    self.fake_start_time = time.time()
    self.x = MyClass(start_time=self.fake_start_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) can be used to pre-bind arguments. So in this case, you can bind the time to the class constructor and then use the bound constructor without passing additional arguments:

```
from functools import partial

class MyclassTest(TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    # Feel free to use a shorter name
    self.FakeTimeMyClass = partial(MyClass, time.time())

  def test_one(self):
    x = self.FakeTimeMyClass()
    ...

  def test_two(self):
    x = self.FakeTimeMyClass()
    ...
```

Comment: This is cool because unlike my solution it allows adding per-test arguments to instantiation.  Nice!